# Moving elements based on mobile view width isn't snapping back to original desktop view

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is kind of a two part question. I have 3 containers that are essentially the same thing. I want to move the image element from where it is in desktop view and move it somewhere else when in mobile view. Here's the jQuery:

```js
checkSize();

$(window).resize(checkSize);

function checkSize() {
    if ($(window).width() <= 480) {
        const oddContainer = ".main-container:nth-child(odd)";

        for (var i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
            let imageSwitch = `.main-container:nth-child(${i}) .body-banner img`;

            $(imageSwitch).prependTo(`.head-banner:nth-child(${i}`);
        }
    } else if ($(window).width() >= 481) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

This is the HTML:

```html
<div class="main-container">
    <div class="head-banner">
        <p class="discount">
            <span>26</span>
        </p>
        <p class="best">
            <span>BEST</span><br> <span id="value">VALUE</span>
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="body-banner">
        <div class="wrapper">
            <div class="supply">
                <p><span class="text-bold">6</span> <span class="text-medium">Month Supply</span></p>
            </div>
            <img src="./assets/1md_advtur6_500x500@2x.png" />
            <div class="discount-price">
                <p class="text-bold">$33.17</p>
                <p class="between"><span id="strike">$45.00 </span><span>each</span></p>
            </div>

            <div class="after-line-break">
                <p class="text-bold green">SAVE $71</p>
                <P class="text-medium supply">Free Shipping!</P>
            </div>
            <button class="button text-bold">
                    ADD TO CART
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="main-container">
    <div class="head-banner">
        <p class="discount">
            <span>15</span>
        </p>
        <p class="best">
            <span>BEST</span><br> <span id="value">SELLER</span>
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="body-banner">
        <div class="wrapper">
            <div class="supply">
                <p><span class="text-bold">3</span> <span class="text-medium">Month Supply</span></p>
            </div>
            <img src="./assets/1md_advtur6_500x500@2x.png" />
            <div class="discount-price">
                <p class="text-bold">$38.33</p>
                <p class="between"><span id="strike">$45.00 </span><span>each</span></p>
            </div>

            <div class="after-line-break">
                <p class="text-bold green">SAVE $20</p>
                <P class="text-medium supply">Free Shipping!</P>
            </div>
            <button class="button text-bold">
                        ADD TO CART
                </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

There are two problems:

1. The function executes when it reaches the correct width range, however, it does not remove the changes when I resize it back to Desktop view.
2. When I move the image from it's original place, it only takes the image from the first container and places it three times in each head-banner class.

I have tried removing the for loop and manually checking to see if moving one image from any other container besides the first one would actually execute and it doesn't. It only executes if my "imageSwitch" variable is equal to: nth-child (1) I just can't seem to figure out why that may be the case.

Comment: Just a question: why are you using jQuery for this? Bootstrap was designed with responsive design in mind.

Comment: Can't use Bootstrap for this one. It's an assignment to execute responsive design without using Bootstrap. I did this before with bootstrap.

Comment: you can achieve it with media queries of css also

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a code for revert. Something like below..

```
checkSize();

$(window).resize(checkSize);

function checkSize() {
    if ($(window).width() <= 480) {
        $(".main-container").each(function(){
            console.log($(this).find(".body-banner img"));
            $(this).find(".body-banner img").prependTo($(this).find(".head-banner"));
        });
    } else if ($(window).width() >= 481) {

        $(".main-container").each(function(){
            $(this).find(".head-banner img").appendTo($(this).find(".body-banner .wrapper>.supply"));
        });
    }
}
```

Test it here.. https://jsfiddle.net/nimittshah/vrzmp0e6/

Comment: .each and this! Of course. I tried a .forEach function and got the same results.  Your solution makes so much more sense than template literals ever could for this problem. Thank you so much. I need to read up more on this and .each. Thanks again.

Comment: You're welcome.. Please accept the answer if it fixes your problem :)

Comment: Quick question, is there a way to have this fire if you load the page from Mobile view, rather than only fire from when I load the page in desktop to view and scale it down? It's odd that it doesn't fire. I was told to use enquire.js to help with this, but I don't think I'm allowed to use libraries.

Comment: It should fire from the Mobile as well.. Make sure you are not loading your page as Desktop view in Mobile. It should be Mobile view. If you are not allowed to use Bootstrap, you can use @mediaquery in CSS for that.. You can read it here https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp